# Jest cleanup after test case failed

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs

What is a good and clean way to cleanup after a test case failed?
For a lot of test cases, I first create a clean database environment, which needs to be cleaned up after a test case finishes.

```
test('some test', async () => {
  const { sheetService, cleanup } = await makeUniqueTestSheetService();

  // do tests with expect()

  await cleanup();
});
```

Problem is: If one of the `expects` fails, `cleanup()` is not invoked and thus the database environment is not cleaned up and jest complains `Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.` because the connection is not closed.

My current workaround looks like this, but it doesn't feel good and clean to push the cleanup hooks to an array which than is handled in the `afterAll` event.

```
const cleanUpHooks: (() => Promise<void>)[] = [];

afterAll(async () => {
  await Promise.all(cleanUpHooks.map(hook => hook()));
});

test('some test', async () => {
  const { sheetService, cleanup } = await makeUniqueTestSheetService();

  // do tests with expect()

  await cleanup();
});
```

Comment: May be this will work if you are using mongo as your database https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-clean.

Comment: I usually delete and restore the database in `afterEach` execution for unit tests because I want them isolated to also been able to run them in parallel to decrease the time spent in the process. If you don't need that level of isolation, restoring the database in the `afterAll` execution it seems enough clean from my point of view.

Comment: @Dez How do you access resources created in a test case from `afterEach`? In my case it would be the database connection.

Comment: the best and safest way is to spin up DB for every test separately. This gives you 100% isolation.

Comment: @MU That's exactly what I am doing at the moment. The question is, how can I safely cleanup the database and connection (that's what the `cleanup` function does), even if a test case fails ;)

Comment: You should initialize db beforeEach so it does not matter if it fails or not

Comment: @MU But then I have to use shared variables in the `beforeEach` and the test cases for the database connection reference, which can lead to some unexpected fails when executed in parallel, right?

Answer (score 8):

Use try/finally block for such cases.

For example:

```
  it("some test case", async done => {
    try {
      expect(false).toEqual(true);
      console.log("abc");
      done();
    }finally{
      console.log("finally");
      // cleanup code below...
    }
  });
```

Above code would just execute the finally block (hence "finally" gets printed in console instead of "abc".
Note that the catch block gives a timeout so just use `finally`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62958360/1291122) answer must be useful.

Answer (score 1):

What if you use afterEach()? it will execute after each test

```
test('some test', async () => {
  const { sheetService, cleanup } = await makeUniqueTestSheetService();

  // do tests with expect()

});

afterEach(async()=>{
    await cleanup();
});
```

Comment: `afterEach` is good for cleaning up items created beforeEach test. What if you create specific objects in one test, and want to clean *those* up at the end of *that* test?

Comment: Might not be a good practice. But you can use an if statement to check for test method name in afterEach.